# Is it possible to share .ASPXAUTH cookie between MVC 5 and .Net core MVC 3.1 applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, forms-authentication

Currently, we are running MVC 5 application with form authentication(*.ASPXAUTH*) and now we are building a new part based on .Net core MVC 3.1.
and we are hosting the MVC 5 application on https://test.admin.com:80
and .Net core MVC3.1 application on https://test.admin.com:82

**Constraint:** User will be login to MVC 5 application (i.e https://test.admin.com:80)
form authentication(*.ASPXAUTH*) will happen, based on some condition they will be redirected to core application(https://test.admin.com:82).

Now the requirement is to consume API's (MVC 5) from the **core application** so I need to read the *.ASPXAUTH* cookie in the core application to authorize the API (MVC 5).

Is it possible to read the *.ASPXAUTH* cookie in the core application??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find the solution?